# Locating a memory leak in the globals with given memory allocation number

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to locate a memory leak in my c++ programm using VS 2019.
The output in the Debug-Output window reads for example:

```
{3880} normal block at 0x00D66730, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < 5      > D8 35 0F 05 00 00 00 00
```

So the memory allocation number is 3880. In order to locate this leak I implemented
a memory leak on purpose using a global variable:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int* foo = DEBUG_NEW int;
```

This leads to an additional message:

```
C:\Main.cpp(5) : {3944} normal block at 0x00D24BF8, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <    > CD CD CD CD
```

So the memory allocation number 3880 is lower then memory allocation number of the on purpose memory leak (3944).
Does this information allow me to draw the conclusion that the memory leak (with memory allocation number 3880) is due to a global variable?
Or is it still possible, that it is a leak due to a DLL-file (or a global variable in a DLL-file)?

Comment: Step into the allocation function until you find the allocation counter, then make a conditional breakpoint that stops when the count is reached. That should show you precisely where the allocation happens.

Comment: @j6t Thanks for your post. With "allocation function" do you mean "inline void* __CRTDECL operator new" in "vcruntime_new.h"? I was not able to find a "allocation counter". Do you have any help?

Comment: Yes, I mean that function. Use context menu, "Step into Specific" whenever possible, and then in the Call stack window, context menu "Load symbols" if they are not loaded; this should show you the source code. You should ultimately end up in some malloc-like function. It looks like it is `heap_alloc_dbg_internal` in `ucrtbased.dll` here, and the variable name to watch out for is `request_number` or `__acrt_current_request_number`.

Comment: There seems to be a global variable `_crtBreakAlloc` that you could set to 3880, and it should automatically stop in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Watch entry `ucrtbased.dll!_crtBreakAlloc`. It's initial value is -1. But you can set it to 3880 to request a stop at that allocation.

To get to that point when the allocation happens during startup is a bit difficult, though.

1. You must set a function breakpoint at `ucrtbased.dll!heap_alloc_dbg_internal`.
2. Run your program. It will stop at that function.
3. Change the value of `ucrtbased.dll!_crtBreakAlloc` to 3880 (which you should have in your Watch window by now).
4. Disable the breakpoint at `heap_alloc_dbg_internal`.
5. Continue the program. Observe your program being halted at the requested allocation.

Comment: I am so grateful for your answer! I will accept it. In your answer in step 1. could you please replace "heap_alloc_dbg_internal" with "ucrtbased.dll!heap_alloc_dbg_internal"?

Comment: Done! Although it worked without that for me for some reason.